# Linux environments. make the machine slow

Tags: linux

This may seem weird, but is there a way to make the machine(linux/unix flavours - preferably RHEL).
I need to control the speed of the machine to make sure the code works on very slow systems and identify the right break point (in terms of time)..

One way i can do it is to run some heavy background process.
Any other smarter way?

Thanks

Comment: Probably this may help: https://wiki.debian.org/HowTo/CpuFrequencyScaling

Comment: Are you talking purely processor speed though? In my experience, CPU being slow is rarely the problem with a 'slow system' but rather memory exhaustion, disk IO, excessive swapping/contention.

Comment: [To produce high CPU load, memory, I/O or stress test Linux server](http://linuxdrops.com/how-to-produce-high-cpu-load-memory-io-or-stress-test-a-linux-server)

Answer (score 2):

**How to produce high CPU load, memory, I/O or stress test Linux server**

Install some prerequisites

**On CentOS/RHEL**

```
yum install gcc gcc-c++ autoconf automake
```

**On Debian, Ubuntu**

```
 sudo su -
 apt-get update
 apt-get install build-essential
```

Download the latest tarball and run configure, make, make install

```
wget http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/repo/pkgs/stress/stress1.0.4.tar.gz/a607afa695a511765b40993a64c6e2f4/stress-1.0.4.tar.gz
 tar zxvf stress-1.0.4.tar.gz
 cd stress-1.0.4
 ./configure
 make
 make install
```

The binary gets installed under /usr/local/bin

To start stress run stress followed by the -c flag for load stress, -m for memory stress, -i for io and -d for HDD. For example to stress cpu execute

```
stress -c 5
```

Execution of the command above will hog all available cpu power and create a load five times a single core would happily handle.

Similarly to stress some memory you can execute

```
 stress -m 512M
```

Answer (score 1):

What you seems to looking for is named in production a **stress test**.

A good start : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_testing_%28software%29

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Stress_Test

Using [stress command line](http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~apw/stress/) :

Example :

```
# yum install stress
# stress --cpu 16 --io 8
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use some emulator, maybe a suitably configured [qemu](http://qemu.org/). If you have the source code of your application you might cross-compile it for e.g. an ARM and emulate that binary (addition benefit: you know that you application can work on some ARM).

And of course you might use Fabrice Bellard's [javascript PC emulator](http://bellard.org/jslinux/) in your browser; it is a slow "PC"

You could also buy some cheap slow Linux running hardware (e.g. [Rasberry Pi](http://www.raspberrypi.org/)). Or run your thing on some old netbook.